# How can I, and does it make sense to, use a Service Worker to add an Authorization header to all my API requests?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, service-worker

Every request I make to an internal API requires an Authorization header. I am building a Polymer-based app using many web components, both private and third-party. I do nearly all of my AJAX calls through `<iron-ajax>` elements. I know that I could create a custom component to achieve the centralization I'm looking for, but I was wondering if using a service worker to intercept requests to my api and add the required headers and any other manipulation or validation I might want would be viable, performant, or even possible. Especially because Polymer 1.0 doesn't support extending other components yet.

Comment: "I know that I could create a custom component" --- I think this is precisely the answer to your question, and a perfect use case for creating a custom component that wraps your `<iron-ajax>` calls.  It's a component that uses

1. static special headers
2. Performs validation
3. Is configurable externally.

All of this screams dom-module to me, and I think a service worker intercepting this and etc., is way more work than it needs to be.  "There's an element for that!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the service worker script as a (java-)scriptable proxy — you could most certainly do any manipulation (including adding, removing and manipulating HTTP Headers) to your calls as long as the service worker controls the origin. And until your API calls are same-origin. Cross-Origin and other opaque request-y stuff gets trickier, but I don't think this applies to your use-case judging from how you described it so far.

The only problem with that approach is that you are basically limiting your app's scope to a single browser: Google Chrome (version 40+). If that's fine by you, feel free to go ahead with this, but since Firefox won't be supporting request capture (the `fetch` event) just yet, *(even though service workers at this point seem to be finally landing in Firefox 43)*, and you can't polyfill service workers — you will *have* to provide some fallback-mechanism **in your page's JS** code if you want to support *any* browser, other than Chrome 40+ at least for several months to come.

Comment: To reinforce this: service workers are meant to be a progressive enhancement, and designing a page that will _only_ work if a service worker is registered is almost certainly a mistake. Even for Chrome users, a SW will (normally) not be active the first time a user visits the site, or if the user shift-reloads one of your pages.

Comment: Thank you both. This adds some clarity to their intended use. I don't think it makes sense to use them. I've realized I can easily hijack the `xhr.open` method to set up listeners and do anything I need there, and for the moment, I've chosen to do this with a Polymer Behavior.